# Highcharts: How to change the border color of RangeSelector Input Boxes in StockCharts?

Tags: css, highcharts

In stock chart there are input boxes to select the dates.

Upon clicking inside the text box a border appears, I want to completely remove this effect?

I tried with:

```
  inputStyle: {
                 select: {
                        fill: '#000',
                        style: {
                            color: 'white'
                        }
                    }

            }
```

and

```
inputStyle: {
        color: '#039',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        borderColor:'#000'
    }
```

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KamranZafar924/dq5e0bk7/). I want to completely remove this bordering effect when the range selector is clicked.

But its not working. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following on your CSS

```
input.highcharts-range-selector:focus {
   outline: none!important;
}
```

Comment: its not `outline` I actually tried with `input.highcharts-range-selector:focus {
    background-color: red;
    outline: none!important;

}`. I can see the red background but outline is still there.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this; Try:

```
input.highcharts-range-selector:focus {
  border: none !important;
  height: 22px !important;
  width: 95px !important;
}
```